# youtube data api search by viewCount wrong results

Tags: youtube-data-api

When I start a GET request to `https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=*channelId*&order=viewCount&key=*apiKey*` I am supposed to get the most viewed videos of the channel.

In the response's `items` array's first element is a 6 months old video with around 4k views.

On the channel's Youtube page if I sort by most viewed, the first one is 10 years old with 200k views.

Any idea why I do not get the correct results?

I double-checked, the channel id is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Easy workaround**:

Use my [YouTube operationnal API](https://yt.lemnoslife.com/), make a GET request to `https://yt.lemnoslife.com/search?part=snippet&channelId=*channelId*&order=viewCount`

**A bit more complicated workaround**:

```bash
curl -s 'https://www.youtube.com/youtubei/v1/browse?key=AIzaSyAO_FJ2SlqU8Q4STEHLGCilw_Y9_11qcW8' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-raw '{"context":{"client":{"clientName":"WEB","clientVersion":"2.9999099"}},"browseId":"CHANNEL_ID","params":"EgZ2aWRlb3MYASAAMAE="}'
```

Don't forget to replace `CHANNEL_ID` with the channelId you want the most viewed videos from.

If you need more than the first 30 results, grab the continuation token from the response of the request above and use the following command (and if you're still interested for more results use the last continuation token you got):

```bash
curl -s 'https://www.youtube.com/youtubei/v1/browse?key=AIzaSyAO_FJ2SlqU8Q4STEHLGCilw_Y9_11qcW8' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-raw '{"context":{"client":{"clientName":"WEB","clientVersion":"2.9999099"}},"continuation":"CONTINUATION_TOKEN"}'
```

Don't forget to replace `CONTINUATION_TOKEN` with the continuation token you got from the latest request reponse.

Note: don't pay attention to the key, it's not a Youtube Data API v3 key.

Comment: Are you saying that what I experience is normal with v3?

Comment: Franckly YouTube Data API v3 is full of bugs, sorry to have to tell you that. But workarounds work !

Comment: I just checked and youtube itself calling v1 for rendering the most viewed videos. :) Thanks.