# Youtube Data API getting wrong results in most viewed in a period

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am exploring the Youtube Data API, and I am trying to get the most viewed videos that were published in a period of time. The problem is, I do not get accurate results. I put my code and a result.

```py
from datetime import datetime
import requests
import json

def get_most_watched_videos(api_key, year_b, month_b, day_b, hour_b, min_b, year_a, month_a, day_a, hour_a, min_a, category_id):
    published_before = datetime(year_b, month_b, day_b, hour_b, min_b).isoformat("T") + "Z"
    published_after = datetime(year_a, month_a, day_a, hour_a, min_a).isoformat("T") + "Z"

    params = {
        'part': 'snippet',
        'maxResults': 10,
        'order': 'viewCount',
        'type': 'video',
        'publishedBefore': published_before,
        'publishedAfter': published_after,
        'region': 'US',
        #'relevanceLanguage': 'en',
        'key': api_key,
    }

    response = requests.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search', params=params)

    return response.json()


year_b, month_b, day_b, hour_b, min_b = 2023, 6, 25, 0, 0
year_a, month_a, day_a, hour_a, min_a = 2010, 6, 24, 0, 0
videos = get_most_watched_videos(api_key, year_b, month_b, day_b, hour_b, min_b, year_a, month_a, day_a, hour_a, min_a, category_id)
video_ids = [video['id']['videoId'] for video in videos['items']]

# get the view count for each video
view_counts = []
video_list = []
for video_id in video_ids:
    response = requests.get(f'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id={video_id}&key={api_key}')
    video = json.loads(response.text)
    video_list.append(video)
    view_count = int(video['items'][0]['statistics']['viewCount'])
    view_counts.append((video_id, view_count))

# sort the videos by view count
view_counts.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

# print the videos and their view counts
for video_id, view_count in view_counts:
    print(f'Video ID: {video_id}, View Count: {view_count}')
```

The results of this function is not accurate in terms of real life views.
Am I using the API in a wrong way? or it does not work?

I have searched for this issue for example on [youtube data api search by viewCount wrong results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70791071/youtube-data-api-search-by-viewcount-wrong-results), but they recommend using the v1 version of the API, which is deprecated.

This is the results I get when running the previous code (they are clearly wrong, because "Despacito" has more than 17M views:

> Video ID: Qpd5dox2GlI, View Count: 17148767
> Video ID: 9tXsku7CQQA, View Count: 13613482
> Video ID: o3cYy7IGQ_w, View Count: 11185616
> Video ID: ygCxKydStJ8, View Count: 9768904
> Video ID: F6MfmV-u2kc, View Count: 7319194
> Video ID: 6weJp1JkFcg, View Count: 5612655
> Video ID: lo7SH3S6zCw, View Count: 4121992
> Video ID: iDMren1gIzw, View Count: 4061525
> Video ID: 9iNrvndVBqE, View Count: 3842975
> Video ID: oYX5v_W3qT0, View Count: 3316633

Sometimes I change the starting date (to a bigger period) and I get lower results.

Comment: im pritty sure if you check the issue forum you will find this has been reported a number of times over the years.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the API only lets you pass through one parameter IE `publishedAfter`, but if you pass both `publishedAfter` and `publishedBefore` through then neither work.